# redirect Django not working blank response

Tags: python, django, redirect

I tried using reverse, no issues there are in django and when i see the response it is simply blank

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def Aviation (request):
    return render(request, 'Aviation/Aviationtest.html')
def SendInformations (request):
    #a lot of uninteresting code
    return redirect(reverse("Aviation"))
```

here's my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.Aviation, name="Aviation"),
path("let_me_send_informations", views.let_me_send_informations, name="let_me_send_informations"),
path("Informations", views.Informations, name="Informations"),
path("SendInformations", views.SendInformations, name="SendInformations")
]
```

I tried using reverse, the complete path, not using reverse and i am sure the directories are set well

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

Change it to:

```
redirect("Aviation")
```

Comment: tried, it does not function

Comment: Well it should. Is the response still blank& whats the path, is the url path the correct one?

Comment: it says no resource with given identifier found but the url should be correct

Comment: if i print redirect("Aviation") it says <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/Aviation/">

Answer (score 0):

you could use the redirect() method without the reverse like this:

```
def SendInformations (request):
    #a lot of uninteresting code
    return redirect("Aviation")
```

checkout the docs to learn more:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: it does not function